# How to supply resource image to ZXing Barcode Scanner via Intent

Tags: android, android-emulator, zxing

I'm trying to use the ZXing Barcode Scanner Intent in an emulator without a camera.

I can see from exhaustive Google searches that it's possible to suppliment Camera with another source. All roads point to http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source, but no examples.

I can't figure out how to use it!

How do I use the barcode scanner without a camera in emulator? Examples would be much, **MUCH** appreciated.

So far I have a simple intent declaration, a Button to `initiateScan()`, and the `onActivityResult` listener to handle the scan result.

Comment: Why you want to use emulator, why not device?

Comment: @Pawan - Why not? I'm not opposed to device testing, but it seems to be a caveat in test driven development. All the questions I find on the web lead to no direct answer. I just don't grasp how to implement the CameraSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're integrating via Intent, then you are using the Barcode Scanner app as-is. (That's a good idea.) However the BS app has no notion of faking the camera on the emulator.

The link you provide is the very best for what you seem to want to do. You change uses of `Camera` to use its `CameraSource` and then slip in the fake implementation, instead of `GenuineCamera`. But, that's a change you make to Barcode Scanner itself. Then you install modified BS on your emulator. Then you test by Intent.

Your app itself needs no changes to work on the emulator.

Comment: Ah, I originally thought that I needed to modify the BS app source. I just didn't want to go down that road in case I was wrong. Thanks for information.